# HorizontalList crash when scroll "too" fast

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4, horizontal-scrolling

I have this strange problem in Flex(Flash Builder 4), in HorizontalList it crash whenever I scroll to fast, anyone got an idea?
here's my Custom item renderer

```
package
{
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.text.StyleSheet;
    import flashx.textLayout.container.ScrollPolicy;
    import mx.containers.VBox;
    import mx.controls.Image;
    import mx.controls.Label;
    import mx.core.FlexGlobals;

    public class CustomItemRenderVBox extends VBox
    {
        private var track:Object = null;
        private var img:Image = new Image();
        private var lbl:Label = new Label();
        [Embed(source="gfx/noArt.png")]
        [Bindable]
        private var noArt:Class;


        override public function set data(value:Object):void
        {
            trace(value);
        if(value.c3 != "" )
        try{
            addChild(img);
            addChild(lbl);

            horizontalScrollPolicy = ScrollPolicy.OFF;
            verticalScrollPolicy = ScrollPolicy.OFF;
            setStyle("verticalAlign", "top");
            setStyle("horizontalAlign","left");
            track = value;
            trace("Art: " + value.Art); 

            if(value.Art == "" || value.Art =="-" )
            img.source = noArt; else    
            img.source = value.Art;  // << when I remove this part it works fine
            trace("GAY");   
            img.height = 60;
            img.scaleContent = true;
            img.autoLoad = true;

            lbl.text = value.c3;
            lbl.width = 67;
            lbl.height = 20;
            trace("WAY");
            img.useHandCursor = true;
            img.buttonMode = true;

            lbl.useHandCursor = true;
            lbl.buttonMode = true;
            trace("NAY");
            img.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,arClick);
            lbl.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,arClick);


        }catch(E:Error)
        {
        }
        }


        private function arClick(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.albumSearch("/album " + track.c3);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem. In google chrome we can see: The instruction at "0x00000000" referenced memory at "0x00000000". The memory could not be "written".
Solution: I tried to set cachePolicy="on" on my scroller instance. you should set this to your  list component (or to scroller skin part)